# Star ratings in iOS 10.2?

Tags: ios, music.app

Most of the articles I'm reading about the latest 10.2 update for iOS claim there is an option in Settings->Music to "Turn on star ratings", but I am not seeing this after updating.

Is this something they introduced in the beta that didn't make the final cut? How do I turn this on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and have been working with Apple tech support all night! PROBLEM SOLVED!

Please try and follow the steps below:

1. Back-up your iPhone;
2. Go to your iTunes library and stat-rate one of your songs;
3. Now, sync your phone again;
4. Go back to Music setting under 'General' and see if 'Show Star rating' switch is there.
5. Switch it on and you will see star-rating for individual songs in music.

Background INFO: Apple removed star rating in iOS 10, so literally all your star ratings were removed and set back to NONE. So, to initialize this function, you would need to 'wake it up' by adding star ratings again for your songs in iTunes.

Hope this helps. 
Good Luck.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, I need to resync so the songs on the phone have a star rating.  I'll try that in the next few hours and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yesss!!! Thank  you, you saved me my own pain in the butt call to Apple tech support!

Answer (score 4):

For me it does show. I'm running iOS 10.2 on my iPhone 6s. I found it under 'Setttings > Music'.

[image: Music Settings]

After that open the Action sheet of a song. And there you find the 'Rate Song...' button. Pressing this button will show a pop up with 'Star Rating'.

[image: Music Action sheet]
[image: Music Rating Empty]
[image: Music Rating Full]

Comment: Strange, I definitely don't have that. I only have "Show Apple Music", "Genius", "Cellular Data", "Downloaded Music", and the "Playback" section. Runnin 10.2 on my SE.

Comment: Did you already restarted your iPhone?

Comment: Yep, and a second time for good measure.